# Steps in analyzing a sharepoint farm?

Tags: 2010

I would request an expert advice to list me some steps in analyzing a sharepoint farm level configurations and steps in setting it up.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For configuration I would start reading here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782552(v=office.14).aspx

To document all settings I would recommend you a tool - http://www.spdockit.com/ (I am not related to the company!)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you a free SharePoint Analyser known as [SPExplorer](http://spexplorer.codeplex.com/)

> SPExplorer is a SharePoint farm analysis and XML capture tool. You can
>   navigate around the structure of your farm and site collections and
>   examine and extract individual sites, lists or more fine-grained
>   elements as XML (CAML) ready for re-use or deployment.

[image]